# Power BI and Snowflake integration, filtering on coordinates gives wrong decimal precision using direct query

Tags: powerbi, decimal, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, precision

I am using snowflake as a data source for PowerBI in combination with direct query mode. In our model there is a table with assets and their locations (latitude, longitude), another table contains some data for those assets.

To represent the location of each asset I am using a map visual, the data itself is shown in a table on the same page.

When the location is selected on the map visual it filters the page by that location, however the table returns an empty set. I have done some research and it seems to fail at the query that power BI sends to the snowflake database. For the lat, lon values I am using the DECIMAL data type with a (11,8) for precision and scale. However the query that is send to snowflake contains the following:

`"LAT" = CAST(55.33513358 as DECIMAL) and "LON" = CAST(3.1152146 as DECIMAL)`

It seems that due to the missing precision and scale it is converted to a value which is not found in the database. I have already set the data type and precision in the "model" tab of powerBI but this only seems to have an effect on the front-end side.

It does work when I switch to import mode, however there is a strong preference for direct query.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?